# Error attempting to create a Cassandra cluster using Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-swarm

I am trying to configure a Cassandra cluster using Docker Swarm.

The containers keep on dying and restarting. Based on logs, it seems to be that they cannot connect to each other.

The cluster does not seem healthy:

```
root@f6d8d694f8d4:/# nodetool describecluster
Cluster Information:
    Name: Test Cluster
    Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSnitch
    DynamicEndPointSnitch: enabled
    Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
    Schema versions:
        UNREACHABLE: [10.0.8.2, 10.0.2.2]
```

This is a snippet of logs:

```
io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.0.2.2:7000
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe$2.run(AbstractEpollChannel.java:576)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
WARN  [OptionalTasks:1] 2022-10-19 20:29:55,349 CassandraRoleManager.java:344 - CassandraRoleManager skipped default role setup: some nodes were not ready
```

Based on the logs, it seems to be that some nodes are not reachable.

This is my Dockerfile, which contains just some tools:

```
FROM cassandra:4.0.6
RUN apt -y update && apt -y install net-tools && apt install iputils-ping
```

And this is my Docker compose file:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  cassandra0:
    image: my_cassandra:latest
    volumes:
      - ./cassandra/0:/var/lib/cassandra 
    networks:
      - cassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS: "cassandra0"
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: "128M"
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: "512M"
    ports:
      - 7000
      - 9072
      - 7199
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
  cassandra1:
    image: my_cassandra:latest
    volumes:
      - ./cassandra/1:/var/lib/cassandra
    networks:
      - cassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS: "cassandra1"
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS: "cassandra0"
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: "128M"
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: "512M"
    ports:
      - 7000
      - 9072
      - 7199
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
  cassandra2:
    image: my_cassandra:latest
    volumes:
      - ./cassandra/2:/var/lib/cassandra
    networks:
      - cassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS: "cassandra2"
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS: "cassandra0"
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: "128M"
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: "512M"
    ports:
      - 7000
      - 9072
      - 7199
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
  cassandra3:
    image: my_cassandra:latest
    volumes:
      - ./cassandra/3:/var/lib/cassandra
    networks:
      - cassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS: "cassandra3"
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS: "cassandra0"
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: "128M"
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: "512M"
    ports:
      - 7000
      - 9072
      - 7199
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
  cassandra4:
    image: my_cassandra:latest
    volumes:
      - ./cassandra/4:/var/lib/cassandra
    networks:
      - cassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS: "cassandra4"
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS: "cassandra0"
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: "128M"
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: "512M"
    ports:
      - 7000
      - 9072
      - 7199
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
networks:
  cassandra:
          external: true
```

This is my overlay network:

```
...
"Name": "cassandra",
        "Id": "w4ooyvfgyuslnlhl0e9tmyfw2",
        "Created": "2022-10-19T22:37:14.60262042+02:00",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.10.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.10.1"
                }
            ]
        }
...
```

The following Docker compose file works, but I cannot see any relevant difference from the previous one. Only I changed were the containers
and the network names.

```
version: "3.2"
  
services:  

  ################################################################
  # The Casandra cluster 
  #   - cassandra-node1
  ################################################################        
  cassandra-001:
    image: my_cassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS: "cassandra-001"
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: "128M"
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: "1024M"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/001:/var/lib/cassandra
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    networks:
      - cluster_net

  ################################################################
  # The Casandra cluster 
  #   - cassandra-node2
  ################################################################        
  cassandra-002:
    image: my_cassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS: "cassandra-002"
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS: "cassandra-001"
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: "128M"
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: "1024M"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/002:/var/lib/cassandra
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    networks:
      - cluster_net

  ################################################################
  # The Casandra cluster 
  #   - cassandra-node3
  ################################################################        
  cassandra-003:
    image: my_cassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS: "cassandra-003"
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS: "cassandra-001"
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: "128M"
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: "1024M"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/003:/var/lib/cassandra
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    networks:
      - cluster_net

  ################################################################
  # The Casandra cluster 
  #   - cassandra-node4
  ################################################################        
  cassandra-004:
    image: my_cassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS: "cassandra-004"
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS: "cassandra-001"
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: "128M"
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: "1024M"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/004:/var/lib/cassandra
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    networks:
      - cluster_net

  ################################################################
  # The Casandra cluster 
  #   - cassandra-node5
  ################################################################        
  cassandra-005:
    image: my_cassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS: "cassandra-005"
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS: "cassandra-001"
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: "128M"
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: "1024M"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/005:/var/lib/cassandra
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    networks:
      - cluster_net

networks:
  cluster_net:
    external:
      name: cassandra
```

Comment: is this a new docker swarm, or have you verified that service to service comms over overlay networks work?

Comment: ps. Once the overlay network is working, you can roll "n" entries of Cassandra into a single service that is managed via `deploy:replicas` and you set `hostname: cassandra{{.Task.Slot}}` to give each instance a unique ip. The volumes directive supports the same service template syntax so you can give each task its own unique volume name too.

Comment: Sorry @ChrisBecke I missed your comment. The containers can reach each other. I just have a doubt about the binding though...

Answer (score 0):

The error stack you posted indicates that the nodes cannot gossip with each other over the private internode port `7000`.

You need to make sure there's network connectivity between the containers and that there is bi-directional route on port `7000`. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your response, I don't see what I'm messing up though. As you might see from the attached files, I did not do anything to prevent such traffic

Comment: The misbehaviour is consistent with docker installed on vms that have firewalld on by default

Comment: @ChrisBecke could you please explain? How would you fix the issue?